# Solving systems of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following eigenvectors which satisfies the system of a homogenous ODE $$x_1 = \left(  
\begin{array}{c}
    t \\
    1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

$$x_2 = \left(  
\begin{array}{c}
    e^t \\
    e^t \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

.
(a) Compute the Wronskian of $x_1$ and $x_2$

(b) Find the original system of equations.

What i tried

(a)The Wronskain is $te^t(t-2)$ and for it to be lineraly indepedent, the Wronskain not equals to $0$ hence $t$ lies in the interval $0<t<2$.

(b) The answer to this part is $$x'=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\\frac{2-2t}{t^2-2t}&\frac{t^2-2}{t^2-2t}\\\end{bmatrix}x$$. I know how to get the eigenvectors from the system of ODE. But now the question require me to work backwards.Im unsure how to do so  from the eigenvectors though. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X(t) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1(t) & x_2(t) \end{bmatrix}$.

The Wronskian is $W(t)=\det X(t) = e^t(t-1)$. The only point at which the Wronskian vanishes is $t=1$, so we should
expect that the system to have some peculiarity at $t=1$.

Then we have
$\dot{X}(t) = A(t) X(t)$ and so, if $W(t) \neq 0$, we have
$A(t) = \dot{X}(t) X(t)^{-1}$. Grinding through the algebraic tedium gives
$A(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -{1 \over t-1} & {t \over t-1} \end{bmatrix}$.

This gives $\dot{x}_1 = x_2$ and $\dot{x}_2 = -{1 \over t-1} x_1 + {t \over t-1} x_2$. Letting $x= x_1$, we see that this reduces to the one dimensional
second order equation
${d^2 x \over dt^2} - {t \over t-1}{d x \over dt} + {1 \over t-1}x = 0$.

For $t \neq 0$ this is equivalent to
$(t-1){d^2 x \over dt^2} - t{d x \over dt} +x = 0$.